# Approximating the roots of an exponential polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, exponential-function, roots, approximation

I am currently working with an exponential polynomial of the form
$$f(x)=a_1 \cdot\exp(\,\lambda_1\cdot x\,) + a_2\cdot \exp(\,\lambda_2 \cdot x\,) + a_3.$$
In my application it is always true that $a_1>0$, $a_2>0$, and $a_3<0$, while $\lambda_1>\lambda_2>0.$ It would seem that these conditions ensure that there is always going to be a unique *real* $x_*$ that satisfies $f(x_*)=0.$

I was wondering whether anyone might have an idea how to approximate $x_*$ in terms of a closed-form expression. So far, I have been solving this equation with a non-linear equation solver - which turns out to be quite the bottleneck in a broader exercise.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Writing down a closed formula for the inverse is probably hopeless in the general case. If $\lambda = \lambda_1/\lambda_2$, we can put $y = e^{\lambda_2 x}$ so that $e^{\lambda_1x} = y^\lambda$, and thus the problem becomes finding a solution  $y$ to the equation
$$ a_1 y^\lambda+a_2 y +a_3=0.$$
Yet if $\lambda$ is an integer value of at least $5$, this problem is famously insolvable by radicals. The case of noninteger $\lambda$ should be even harder. I reckon the problem is only doable when the ratio $\lambda = \lambda_1/\lambda_2$ is $2$, $3$, or $4$.

Comment: Could you try what I did propose and let me know. Cheers :-)

Comment: in addition to Glare's comment: If $\lambda$ is a rational number, we have an algebraic equation. The following article lists all kinds of algebraic equations that are solvable in radicals. Ritt, J. F.: On algebraic functions which can be expressed in terms of radicals. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 24 (1922) (1) 21-30 https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1922-024-01/S0002-9947-1922-1501211-X

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the most general case, there is no closed form solution but, using the given conditions, I suppose that we can make approximations which would make the solver more happy.
$$f(x)=a_1\, e^{\lambda_1  x} + a_2\,e^{\lambda_2  x} + a_3$$
All derivatives are positive; so a unique solution  $\quad\color{red}{\text{if}\,\,(a_1+a_2+a_3 <0)}$

The double inequality
$$(a_1+a_2)\,e^{\lambda_2  x}<a_1\, e^{\lambda_1  x} + a_2\,e^{\lambda_2  x}<(a_1+a_2)\,e^{\lambda_1  x}$$ makes the root
$$\color{red}{x_1}=\frac 1{\lambda_1}\log \left(-\frac{a_3}{a_1+a_2}\right)< x <\frac 1{\lambda_2}\log \left(-\frac{a_3}{a_1+a_2}\right)=\color{red}{x_2}$$

Since $f(x_2)>0$, by Darboux theorem, starting from $x_2$, Newton iterations will converge without any overshoot of the solution.

Now, we can do a bit better considering
$$g(x)=\log\Big[a_1\, e^{\lambda_1  x}\Big] - \log\Big[-a_3-a_2\,e^{\lambda_2  x}  \Big]=\lambda_1  x+\log(a_1)- \log\Big[-a_3-a_2\,e^{\lambda_2  x}  \Big]$$ which is more linear. Drawing a straight line, another estimate to start with is
$$x_3=\frac{g(x_1)\, x_2-g(x_2)\, x_1}{g(x_1)-g(x_2)}$$

Just an example : $a_1=1$, $\lambda_1=4.56$, $a_2=5.67$, $\lambda_2=1.23$, $a_3=-123456789$ give $x_1=3.66969$, $x_2=13.6047$, $x_3=4.06910$. Just for the fun, plot $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ for $x_1 \leq x \leq x_2$.

Now, Newton iterations for $g(x)$ using $x_3$ as a starting point :
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 4.0691027223043877784 \\
 1 & 4.0858321874716327938 \\
 2 & 4.0858321871513902535
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is the solution for $20$ significant figures.

**Edit**

May be, you could save computer resources working directly with $g(x)$ which, with $x_0=0$ gives
$$x_1=\frac 1 {\lambda_1-\frac{a_2 \lambda_2}{a_2+a_3} }\log \left(-\frac{a_2+a_3}{a_1}\right)$$ For the worked example, this gives $x_1=\color{red}{4.08583}37$.

A little bit better : the first iterate of Halley method is

$$x_1=- \frac {2 g(0) g'(0)} {2 {[g'(0)]}^2 - g(0) g''(0)}$$

$$g(0)=\log \left(-\frac{a_1}{a_2+a_3}\right)\qquad g'(0)=\lambda _1-\frac{a_2 \lambda _2}{a_2+a_3}\qquad g''(0)=-\frac{a_2 a_3 \lambda _2^2}{(a_2+a_3)^2}$$

Comment: That works amazingly well. Against typical parameter values for $a_1, a_2, a_3, \lambda_1,$ and $\lambda_2$ (as furnished by my problem) it does take about 6-7 Newton iterations in order to reach the desired level of precision, but what you are proposing is so so much faster than what I did beforehand. Timing the root-finding step in my code, things went from 0.1885 to 0.003 sec. The most striking advantage is that I can implement your solution in a vectorized manner at negligible computational cost. That is exactly what I have been looking for. Thank you so much.

Comment: @J.Beck. Do not forget that you need  $(a_1+a_2+a_3 <0)$. Have a look at my edit.

Comment: Many thanks your edit. That was very helpful. I ended up working with $f(x)$ and Halley's methods initializing at $x_2$. It would seem that - while in principle more efficient - $g(x)$ also has its drawbacks. In particular, I made my way into regions of the parameter space where $-a_3-a_2\exp(\lambda_2 x)<0$ - at least at some point during the first couple of iterations. Halley's method applied to $f$ does, however, yield the desired degree of precision in typically no more than 4 iterations. Thank you so very much for your help!

Comment: @J.Beck I would rather suggest starting with $x_0=\dfrac2{b_1+b_2}\log\left(-\dfrac{a_3}{a_1+a_2}\right)$, which is a sort of average of the bounds that are provided here.